# Sequence of rows having max sum with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

```
                             Energy
2020-04-02 00:00:00+03:00    1
2020-04-02 00:15:00+03:00    12
2020-04-02 00:30:00+03:00    32
2020-04-02 00:45:00+03:00    45
2020-04-02 01:00:00+03:00    60
2020-04-02 01:15:00+03:00    60
2020-04-02 01:30:00+03:00    70
2020-04-02 01:45:00+03:00    84
2020-04-02 02:00:00+03:00    90
2020-04-02 02:15:00+03:00    81
2020-04-02 02:30:00+03:00    70
2020-04-02 02:45:00+03:00    50
```

I want to find N different rows having maximum sum in the Energy column, 
**For example**

```
2020-04-02 01:30:00+03:00     70
2020-04-02 01:45:00+03:00     84
2020-04-02 02:00:00+03:00     90
2020-04-02 02:15:00+03:00     81
```

The sum of 4 rows should be = 325

Is there a way to achieve this? I am struggling to optimize the sum 
What if I want to find the max sum of 5, 6, 7 or more rows?

**Update**
subset may contain min one row and max total number of rows in the dataframe. The set can have any row, the only criteria is that the sum should be maximum.

Comment: Do you mean you want this list be sorted, or do you want to get a subset of this list where the total energy is at maximum?

Comment: @GrandPhuba
Yes exactly I want to get a subset of this list where the total energy is at maximum

Comment: A subset of a fixed number of consecutive rows?

Comment: The question is unclear. As soon as you are able to formulate the problem comprehensibly and reproducible, you will probably be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: @HafizQasim define the rules of this subset. e.g. how many items can it contain, which rows can be in it, etc.